# CI pipeline doesn't run automatically when included .yml contains workflow rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to include an external GitLab CI YAML file into my project local `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. The external YAML, which is in my other GitLab project `ci/cd > templates` contains some ***workflow rules***:

```yaml
# ci-cd.yml

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$TRACK != null' # TRACK is the environment type (staging/production)
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^trigger|pipeline|web|api$/'
      when: always
```

Below is my project local `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
include:
- '/.gitlab-ci-test.yml'
- project: 'ci-cd/templates'
  file: 'ci-cd.yml'

...
```

The problem is - none of the jobs I have defined inside locally included `.gitlab-ci-test.yml` get triggered when I push the changes to GitLab, even when the job has `when: always` set. Seems like the workflow rules in external `ci-cd.yml` are not letting the jobs run.

I've also tried to locally add a workflow rule to `.gitlab-ci.yml` that evaluates to true, because the [GitLab workflow keyword docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#workflow) say

> When no rules evaluate to true, the pipeline does not run.

That means if any one of the rules evaluates to true, pipeline should have run, which did not happen when I added a local workflow rule.

**EDIT** -  the external file which has workflow rules is used by many projects so this can't be modified to have "push" in $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE. My intention is to let it be as a global rule and try to 'override' locally in my project.

I hope I was clear in issue description. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [push](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) event for `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` in you workflow rule.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$TRACK != null' # TRACK is the environment type (staging/production)
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^trigger|pipeline|push|web|api$/'
      when: always
```

EDIT: if you are not able to change the `workflow` rule in the included file, the only option I see is to duplicate the `workflow` in your `gitlab-ci.yml` and add the missed `push` there.
`workflow` rules take precedence before all other rules and it is not possible to merge two `workflow` blocks. If a `worfklow` block is used in an included yml file and the `gitlab-ci.yml` itself, the `workflow` from the `gitlab-ci.yml` is used. You can check this in `CI/CD` -> `Editor` -> `View merged YAML` in gitlab.

```
include:
  - '/.gitlab-ci-test.yml'
  - project: 'ci-cd/templates'
    file: 'ci-cd.yml'

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$TRACK != null' # TRACK is the environment type (staging/production)
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^trigger|pipeline|push|web|api$/'
      when: always

...
```

Comment: Actually, this file which has workflow rules is handled by a different team and can't be changed because it will affect many projects using it. My intention is to let it be as a global rule and try to 'override' locally in my project.

Comment: one more question please :) If instead of duplicating those 2 existing workflow rules, if I just add one workflow rule locally inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`, say - just for `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"`, will the local workflow rule be considered "in addition to" the 2 global workflow rules (making it 3rd), or it will "overwrite" all values of $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE (trigger|pipeline|web etc) in global and only accept "push" now? When I was previously trying to add a local workflow rule, I was doing it in included file and not main file, that's why maybe it didn't work.

Comment: unfortnately it will not add a 3rd rule but replace `workflow` altogether